# How to handle comma in streamreader

Tags: c#

I am using following function in my code. But if a row has a comma it is splitting row and at the time of storing record in datatable, it gets into the next column.

```
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(file);
string[] headers = sr.ReadLine().Split(',');

foreach (string header in headers)
{
    dt.Columns.Add(header);
}
while (!sr.EndOfStream)
{
    string[] rows = sr.ReadLine().Split(',');
    DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
    for (int i = 0; i < headers.Length; i++)
    {
        dr[i] = rows[i];
    }
    dt.Rows.Add(dr);
}
```

Comment: If your data can contain comma's, don't use a comma as separator. Not much you can do about this

Comment: I think that is the only way.  Unless you wish to insert delimiters into the input text in the first place?

Comment: CSV (Comma Separated Values) is a very common data format for data stored in text files.  Parsing it isn't very complicated but String.Split() won't cut it, you do have to pay attention to fields that are double-quoted.  And can therefore contain commas.  Plenty of libraries out there that help you do this without writing your own code.  In .NET you have the TextFieldParser class to take care of this.